# Difficulty Exporting to OBJ - Texture Clamping

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I have a model that utilizes clamping for its textures. When I export to OBJ, these clamps are lost and the model looks terrible. Is there a way for me to have the OBJ save the clamping?

So here is an image of the problem

[image]

The one on the left, that's how it's supposed to look. You can see an obvious difference on legs and pelvis, I'm sure.

These issue is, it doesn't seem to export the clamping. Is this really something that cannot be exported? I did not even build this model in blender originally.

It just seems like there has to be an easy fix for this that I'm missing.

So to break down what happens. I import the model into blender originally, it looks fine. I make some minor tweaks to it, still looks fine. I then export the file to OBJ via blender's export feature and it loses all clamping for some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please add more information to your question buy [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135888/edit) and [adding images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post), because - you know... "looks terrible" is such a broad term, it could mean anything.

Comment: @metaphor_set thank you, I made some changes based on your comment. Hopefully this make it more clear.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I don't think that answers my question. It's not a lack of textures. It's just texture clamping. My textures appear, just not correctly. I have to imagine something as simple as texture clamping can be exported. Perhaps I'm wrong though